# Saving not working with knockout viewModel?

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application

When I Add a card in my view, I call this:

```
innerModel.addCard = function() {
                // This just adds a card to the UI
                var card = new cardViewModel(addCardDto);
                innerModel.cards.push(card);
            }.bind(this);
```

This adds an empty card to the UI and lets the user input some information.  When they click "Save", I send this bare-minimum package over the wire, save it serverside, and then return a fuller object.  the same goes for Updating - I send only what's needed, and get back a full object.  Here's my cardViewModel:

```
var cardViewModel = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

        self.isNew = ko.observable(false);

        // If the card hasn't been created yet, it won't have a cardId
        if (typeof this.cardId === 'undefined') {
            this.isNew(true);
        }

        this.save = function() {
            // Implement API call here, one for POST, one for PUT.  For now: 
            // Currently just using a hard-coded piece of data 'cardDto' that mocks the result of an API call
            var result = new cardViewModel(cardDto);  // Problem is somewhere around here
            result.editing(false);
            result.isNew(false);
            debugger;
            // trying to re-assign the object to the result here, but it's not working.  No errors from javascript, just no activity when I click "save".
            self = result;
        };

    };
```

From my view I have:

```
<a data-bind="click: save">save</a>
```

This was working before, when my save method was just this:

```
this.save = function() {
                // Implement API call here, one for POST, one for PUT.  For now: 
                this.editing(false);
                this.isNew(false);
     };
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried this:

```
this.save = function() {
            // Implement API call here, one for POST, one for PUT.  For now: 
            // Currently just using a hard-coded piece of data 'cardDto' that mocks the result of an API call
            var result = new cardViewModel(cardDto);  // Problem is somewhere around here
            result.editing(false);
            result.isNew(false);
            debugger;
            // trying to re-assign the object to the result here, but it's not working.  No errors from javascript, just no activity when I click "save".

            ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self); // NEW
        };
```

But chrome dies without any errors or anything when I run this, it just says "Aw snap".

Edit: I ran in IE and I get a "call stack size exceeded error".  Digging into it now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self = result` reassigns the variable `self` to result, it doesn't cause the object to update itself or any of its properties. There is nothing special about `self` that would change how JS assignment works.

Just call `ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, this)` to update the object.

Comment: thanks again for the help.  I tried this (but with ko.mappingfromJS(resullt, {}, self) and chrome just dies when I run it with the "Aw snap" message - no js errors.  Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Figured it out - "result" should have been "cardDto" in the last call to mapping while I simulate.  I was passing in a new setViewModel.